# Using .length() in Java

Tags: java

I have to enter something like `John Doe 12345 99` where First name is `John`, last name is `Doe`, ID is `12345`, and wage is `99`. It needs to be all in one string separated by spaces. So I have this:

```
  while(x < Info.length()){
      if(Info.charAt(x) == ' '){
          First = Info.substring(0,x);
          Last = Info.substring(x + 1, Info.length());
          IDNum = Integer.parseInt(Info.substring(x + 2, Info.length())); 
          Wage = Double.parseDouble(Info.substring(x + 3, Info.length()));
          x = Info.length();
      }
   ++x;
}
```

I'm having trouble on the `.length();` The example in the book only showed how to break up a string with two words in it. It's the length on `IDNum` and `Wage`. I'm not sure where to start them and end them. I think I need to change the ending for the `length()` when the Last calls it.

Comment: This isn't related to your `length()` problem, but a simpler solution would be to use [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Personally, I'd use `String#split`, but, if the requirements preclude, you can also make use [`String#indexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) or [`String#indexOf(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-int-) or even [`String#indexOf(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-)

Comment: @MadProgrammer So if I use String#indexOf(int) I can just set the int to update by counting the spaces?

Comment: @AlexanderWilde It kind of depends, `String#indexOf(int)` will return the "first" index of the character (or `-1` if it doesn't exist), what I would do after that is use `String#indexOf(int, int)` or it's variant to get the next space AFTER the specified index

Comment: Someone needs to say this: The standard Java convention is that variable names (class-level, instance-level, method-parameter, local) should start with a lower-case letter.  `first = info.substring(0,x);` etcetera.

Answer (score 3):

If it's separated by a space why not use the `split()` method:

```
String info = "John Doe 12345 99";
String[] seperatedInfo = info.split(" ");
String firstName = seperatedInfo[0];
String lastName = seperatedInfo[1];
int ID = Integer.parseInt(seperatedInfo[2]);
double pay = Double.parseDouble(seperatedInfo[3]);
System.out.println(firstName);
System.out.println(lastName);
System.out.println(ID);
System.out.println(pay);
```

*Output:*

```
John
Doe
12345
99
```

Also side note Java naming conventions for variables is to start with lower case and use camelCase

Comment: I know I was looking around on stack, and this looked like a good idea. It's homework and the chapter didn't cover anything about using split().

Comment: @AlexanderWilde what did it cover?

Comment: Comparing strings, parsing, breaking a string up into two strings, characters with some methods (Upper, lower, ect), finding length, empty and null strings, and substrings.

Comment: @AlexanderWilde How did they break up a `String`? Using the `split()` method is just another way to break up a `String`

Comment: They used what I did above. They just used the length method to find the beginning of the string then the first space, then started the search for the second word in the string by using the first space to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

So, assuming you're not allowed to use something like `String#split`, which would be my personally preferred method, you could, instead, make use of the `indexOf` functionality, which supplies a couple of different ways to find the index of the a given character or `String` within a `String`.

So, something like...

```
String text = "John Doe 12345 99";
int index = text.indexOf(" ");
int lastIndex = 0;
while (index > -1) {
    String part = text.substring(lastIndex, index);
    System.out.println("[" + part + "]");
    lastIndex = index + 1;
    index = text.indexOf(" ", lastIndex);        
}
if (lastIndex != 0) {
    String part = text.substring(lastIndex);
    System.out.println("[" + part + "]");
}
```

prints out...

```
[John]
[Doe]
[12345]
[99]
```

What I would do, is modify the above to maintain a "counter", which represents the current element you are "extracting" and then add that to the corresponding array element

*Caveat*: This will work for single "spaces" only, so just beware of that.  You could also make use of `String#trim` to trim of leading and trailing spaces, but would require you to manually disassemble the `String` (using `String#substring`)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can parse that `String`, I would start by `split`ing it; then assign the *tokens* as desired. Something like,

```
String info = "John Doe 12345 99";
String[] tokens = info.split("\\s+");
String first = tokens[0], last = tokens[1];
int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
double wage = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
System.out.printf("%d %s, %s %.2f%n", id, last, first, wage);
```

Which outputs

```
12345 Doe, John 99.00
```

Filling `tokens` without `split` is still the approach I would take if limited in the methods I can use. You know there are four tokens, and you can use successive calls to `indexOf(char)` to find spaces. Like,

```
String info = "John Doe 12345 99";
int p = 0, c = 0;
String[] tokens = new String[4];
while (c < 4) {
    int p1 = (c != 3) ? info.indexOf(' ', p) : info.length();
    tokens[c] = info.substring(p, p1);
    p = p1 + 1;
    c++;
}
```

The rest of the answer above does not need to change.

Comment: I can only use loops and if statements to pull parts out of the string. It seems like the difference between Pre-Calc and Calc. I'm at the long way to do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use StringTokenizer class.

**Example**:

```
    String str = "John Doe 12345 99";
    String delimeter = " ";
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, delimeter);
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
    }
```